# How to get db column value from Mybatis for sharding?

Tags: mybatis

I use Mybatis to access db, and some tables is sharding by id with hash algorithm.

I want to write a Mybatis intecepter to change table name automatic, it need to get the sharding column value.

Table Entity:

```
@Data
@TableName("m_user")
public class User {
    @TableId(type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

UserMapper sql:

```
@Select("select * from m_user where id = #{id2} and name = #{name2};")
List<User> selectByIdAndName(Integer id2, String name2);
```

I use `boundSql.getParameterObject()` and `boundSql.getParameterMappings()` to check, but I can not make sure whether the sharding column `id` is in sql and then get the value of the sharding column.

ParameterMappings values and ParameterObject values are here:

```
parameter mapping:ParameterMapping{property='id2', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}
parameter mapping:ParameterMapping{property='name2', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}
```

```
params:{id2=1, param1=1, name2=name1, param2=name1}
```

The parameters are Mapper function parameters, but I need sharding column `id` and value, program can only get `id2` or `param1`.

How to get the db column and value from Mybatis?

Comment: You question is not clear. Are you asking how to figure out in general case which parameter that is passed to mapper is the value that is compared with the `id` column? Or are you asking how to figure out which column is the key column in the result?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to figure out in general case which parameter that is passed to mapper is the value that is compared with the `id` column.